# Setting Xcode Environment Variable from CMake

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I'm working in an `Xcode` project created using `CMake`. I would like to be able to automatically create an environment variable in `Xcode` using `CMake` commands, but it doesn't appear to work.

In my `.profile` I have

```
export WORKDIR=$HOME/temp/working
```

and I would like to have it appear in `Xcode` as an environment variable such as the follow picture (or equivalent)

[image: screenshot]

so that I can load it in C++ using the following:

```
auto workdir  = std::getenv("WORKDIR");
```

I tried using the following command:

```
set($ENV{WORKDIR} ${WORKDIR})
```

but it didn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it as the following in an initial cache file

```
set(CMAKE_XCODE_SCHEME_ENVIRONMENT
  ASAN_OPTIONS=$ENV{ASAN_OPTIONS}
  LSAN_OPTIONS=$ENV{LSAN_OPTIONS} CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
```

to be used as `cmake -C thefile.cmake -G Xcode ..`

or

```
-DCMAKE_XCODE_SCHEME_ENVIRONMENT="ASAN_OPTIONS=${ASAN_OPTIONS};LSAN_OPTIONS=${LSAN_OPTIONS}"
```

to be used by passing it to `cmake` directly.